# Upgrading to SSD but still slow boot

Tags: boot, ssd, startup

I have recently replaced the hard drive of my Dell Precision M4800 with a Samsung EVO 850 SSD (250GB), and would expect a boot time of less than 10s, but in the current state it takes ~27s:

> Startup finished in 3.734s (firmware) + 3.345s (loader) + 6.530s
>   (kernel) + 12.877s (userspace) = 26.487s

I attach here the outputs of `dmesg` and `systemd-analyze plot` commands:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4yzpzC3QL6-OEplNzlyMlpBSTA
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4yzpzC3QL6-X1ZWblVBNmJFV3M

From the output, a big bottleneck in the userspace stage lies at **NetworkManager-wait-online.service (11.433s)**. A solution I found via Google is to disable this service:

```
systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

but I'm not sure if it's safe to do so. Any comments on this will be appreciated.

Apart from userspace, I find that the other stages **(firmware + loader + kernel) also took a long time**. Could you please suggest some improvements?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

---

**Update** with the output of `systemd-analyze blame`. The output is for the latest boot of the device at my school, which is a bit faster (and I don't know why):

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
          6.883s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
           649ms lvm2-monitor.service
           560ms plymouth-start.service
           279ms dev-sda2.device
           114ms networking.service
           105ms accounts-daemon.service
            96ms ModemManager.service
            91ms lightdm.service
            86ms gpu-manager.service
            78ms loadcpufreq.service
            75ms systemd-logind.service
            72ms thermald.service
            70ms upower.service
            57ms irqbalance.service
            55ms NetworkManager.service
            53ms grub-common.service
            52ms avahi-daemon.service
            52ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
            51ms bluetooth.service
            48ms ondemand.service
            47ms virtualbox-guest-utils.service
            46ms apparmor.service
            45ms speech-dispatcher.service
```

Comment: Give it a try, if you face problems you can run `systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service` to re-enable it again.

Comment: can you also post the output of `systemd-analyze blame` ?  -- Don't disable networkmanager service , that's too radical. You could also disable wifi in the Networkmanager configuration panel or uncheck `Enable Networking` in the same panel. That's less radical.

Comment: @knb Thanks. I have updated the question with the output of `systemd-analyze blame`. Could you please have a look?